# How to keep only one element if there are more than one

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Every time I load a page, I have a random number of elements with the same class and different(random) IDs.

I would like to know how I can keep only one element on the page  and delete the others from DOM,  according to their class?

Example:

```
<div id="joke" class="hey"></div>
<div id="joking" class="hey"></div>
<div id="jokes" class="hey"></div>
<div id="joker" class="hey"></div>
```

I would like to leave only `id="joke"` where `joke` (as for the other element's id values) is **randomly/dynamically** generated.

Comment: Wow... Seems as though everyone missed the random part.

Comment: @Paul: I understood it that way, that the IDs are dynamically generated (so you cannot select by ID), not that a random element should be kept. But yes, it is possible to understand in a different way.... OP has to clarify.

Comment: @Felix Ah, I see how it could be read like that. I think he meant he wanted to generate a random id and keep only that one, but you could also be right.

Comment: ids are randonly/dynamically generated :P so i can't keep ids first :P  thx ;)

Comment: @lspuk: That does not not really clarify the issue. Do you want to keep a random element of those or just the first one?

Comment: right... sorry for that. i would like to keep only the first one ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want to keep the first one:

```
$('.hey').slice(1).remove();
```

**Reference:** [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/), [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Answer (score 3):

If you want the first one, you can use:

```
$(".hey").first();
```

If you want a random element from those matched, you can use the `:random` filter implemented [here](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/jquery-random-filter/) and do:

```
$(".hey:random");
```

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that there are only answers here that assume jQuery is available. While obviously jQuery is without a doubt perfect and should be elected president I'm going to assume that it's NOT available. Let's do this (removing all except the first element) just using the DOM shall we. (see [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nEsyt/))

```
<div id="foo">
    <!-- a jocular comment -->
    <div id="joke" class="hey">1</div>
    <div id="joking" class="hey">2</div>
    <div id="jokes" class="hey">3</div>
    <div id="joker" class="hey">4</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('foo'),
    elems = parent.childNodes, // live list
    firstElemNode,
    i = 0;

while (elems[i] && elems[i].nodeType != 1) {
    i++;
}

if (elems[i]) {
   firstElemNode = parent.removeChild(elems[i]);
   parent.innerHTML = '';
   parent.appendChild(firstElemNode);
}
```

We look for the first node that is an element (not a text node or comment node). If we can't find one we are smart enough to do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

```
var $els = $('.hey');
$els.not($els.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*$els.length))).remove();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/bhs7K/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.hey').not('#joke').remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.hey:not(:first)').remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

To show a *random* .hey element:

```
$('.hey').hide();
$('.hey')[Math.floor(Math.random()*$('.hey').length)].show();
```